# Error while solving system of equations

Tags: matlab, error-handling, type-conversion, equation-solving

I received a negative MATLAB response while inserting the following requests:

```
syms x y z
solve (x+y==z,x-2*y==z,[x,y],'ReturnConditions', false)
```

I wanted to get `x`, and `y` in terms of `z` but, alas, I got the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> char
>   Conversion to char from logical is not possible.
>
> Error in ==> solve>getEqns at 160
>     vc = char(v);
>
> Error in ==> solve at 84
>   [eqns,vars] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Any help please?

Comment: I can't replicate your error.  I'm on MATLAB R2015a.

Comment: @rayryeng any alternate solutions ?

Comment: Try wrapping the variables in a cell array.  In previous versions of MATLAB, I had to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a cell array to wrap `x` and `y` instead:

```
>> syms x y z
>> X = solve (x+y==z,x-2*y==z,{x,y},'ReturnConditions', false);
>> X.x
ans =
z
>> X.y
ans =
0
```

This was required for previous versions of MATLAB.  However, I'm using R2015a currently and your code works for me.  I can't replicate your error.  You may be using a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the hit-back to my problem.

As for solving system of two equations and two variables, we use a matrix of inputs, and outputs must be sprecified.

> ```
> b=[x+y-z;x-3*y-z;]
> ```

```
b =

x + y - z
x - 3*y - z
```

> ```
> [e t]=solve(b,x,y)
> ```

```
e =

z


t =

0
```

Thnk you all.